# App title hidden?

Tags: ios, applications, jailbreak

[image]

Why is the SE app title hidden?
I'm jailbroken on iOS 8.1

Answer (score 1):

Try respringing.

If you have SSH access, login as root or mobile (doesn't matter which) and type

```
respiring
```

This will temporarily make your phone freeze. It will bring you back to the lock screen when done.

Alternatively, if you don't know how to install/use SSH, install

```
SBSettings
```

from Cydia. It will respiring your device when it's done. (When you have installed this, and need to respiring for some reason, swipe right on the status bar to bring up SBSettings.

Answer (score 0):

because either the app or your jailbreak went wrong somewhere.
It shows just fine on my phone.

Try re-installing the app, or in iTunes - Backup; Reset; Restore.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the Springboard cache by running `uicache` as mobile then respringing.

Comment: @Stefan As your device is jailbroken, SSH into the device as the mobile user instead of root and run `uicache` to clear the cache.